# Code script to sort users by values of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have inherited a script that does not appear to work as intended. 
I have a table listing id number identifying users, alongside their points and position (which is based on the highest number of points).

The script is meant to look at whoever user has the same points as another and sort them in position based on the values of another table which lists individual event results. The tie breaker is the highest position achieved.

E.g.
User A and User B are tied in 4th place and all have accrued 50 points. However, User B's best result over the various events was a 2nd place, whereas User A's was 3rd. Therefore, the script should place User B in 4th place and User A in 5th.
Similarly, were both users to have the same best result, the script would look at the second best result, and so on.

This is the code I have and, from my understanding, SHOULD work (but it doesn't).

$season_id, $season_start, $season_end, $compId are all variables that are declared previously.

```
    $roundsarray = array();
$roundstotal=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '$season_start' AND '$season_end' AND competition='$compId' AND tag!='T' ORDER BY eventDate ASC");
$roundsnum = mysql_num_rows($roundstotal);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
    $roundsarray[]=$row['id'];
}

$datafirst=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '$season_start' AND '$season_end' AND competition='$compId' AND tag!='T' ORDER BY eventDate ASC LIMIT 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($datafirst)) {   $firstevent = $row[0];  }

$datalast=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '$season_start' AND '$season_end' AND competition='$compId' AND tag!='T' ORDER BY eventDate DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($datalast)) {    $lastevent = $row[0];   }

$racesessions = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT eventSession FROM results WHERE eventID>='$firstevent' AND eventID<='$lastevent' AND compId='$compId' AND eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA')");
$racesnum = mysql_num_rows($racesessions);
$totalsessions = $racesnum*$roundsnum;

$points = "SELECT DISTINCT points FROM standings_drivers WHERE season='$season_id' ORDER BY points DESC";
$ptcom = mysql_query($points);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($ptcom)) {
    $points_pos = $row[0];

    $numpoints = "SELECT driver FROM standings_drivers WHERE season='$season_id' AND points='$points_pos'";
    $numpts = mysql_query($numpoints);
    $amount = mysql_num_rows($numpts);

    if ($amount==1) {}
    if ($amount>1) {

        $numpointsfirst = "SELECT driver, position FROM standings_drivers WHERE season='$season_id' AND points='$points_pos' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1";
        $num1stpts = mysql_query($numpointsfirst);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($num1stpts)) {
            $driver1_id = $row[0];
            $driver1_pos = $row[1];
        }
        $numpointslast = "SELECT driver, position FROM standings_drivers WHERE season='$season_id' AND points='$points_pos' ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 1";
        $numlstpts = mysql_query($numpointslast);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($numlstpts)) {
            $driverl_id = $row[0];
            $driverl_pos = $row[1];
        }


        $orderbit = "ORDER BY position1";
        $superquer = "SELECT SD.driver, 

             COALESCE((SELECT R.position FROM results R 
             WHERE R.driverId = SD.driver AND R.compId='$compId' 
             AND R.eventID>='$firstevent' AND R.eventID<='$lastevent' 
             AND R.eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
             ORDER BY R.position 
             LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0), 999) AS position1";

             $i=2;
             $max = $totalsessions+1;

            while ($i<$max) {

                $superquer .= ", COALESCE((SELECT R$i.position FROM results R$i 
                 WHERE R$i.driverId = SD.driver AND R$i.compId='$compId' 
                 AND R$i.eventID>='$firstevent' AND R$i.eventID<='$lastevent' 
                 AND R$i.eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
                 ORDER BY R$i.position 
                 LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i), 999) AS position$i";

                $orderbit .= ", position$i";

                $i++;
            }                


        $superquer .= " FROM standings_drivers SD 
        WHERE SD.season = '$season_id' AND SD.points='$points_pos'";

        $orderbit .= ";";

        $querytotl = "$superquer $orderbit";

        $sqres = mysql_query($querytotl);
        if($sqres === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }
        $n=0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sqres)) {
            $driver_id = $row[0];

            $name = "SELECT CONCAT (firstName, ' ', lastName) AS username FROM users WHERE id='$driver_id'";
            $nameres = mysql_query($name);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($nameres)) {
                $name=$row[0];
            }

            $pos=$driver1_pos+$n;

            $query12 = "UPDATE standings_drivers SET position='$pos' WHERE driver='$driver_id' AND season='$season_id'";
            mysql_query($query12);

            $n++;
        }
    }       
}
```

Problem - the script correctly identifies the users level on points and manages the first step of ordering, but fails to order them in the correct order when the highest score is the same.

I didn't write the original piece of code and I am a bit lost over what to do! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your level of coding ability.  Personally I would just rewrite it.  If you know what the proper functionality should be, you'll likely spend more time trying to fix and refactoring  it then just it writing it yourself.

Comment: Just looking at it, there are way to many singular queries, you may be able to significantly reduce it by using a couple well placed JOIN.  I cant say that for sure without looking at it in more detail.  But when I see over a dozen queries, it seems less then optimal.

Comment: you can replace your first while loop and your second and third query with this

`while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($roundstotal)) {
    $roundsarray[]=$row;
}
/*doing a reset just to be sure you can probably do without one*/
$firstevent = current(reset($roundsarray)); 
$lastevent = end($roundsarray);` and that would be a great improvment for starters